# JSF converts whitespaces to &nbsp;

Tags: jsf

I have a problem:

```
<h:outputLabel>#{msgService.getMessage('diseases.Z82.8')}</h:outputLabel>
```

The value of the string in EL is "Brown fox jumps over the dog". But in HTML output I have:

```
<label>Brown&nbsp;fox&nbsp;jumps&nbsp;over&nbsp;the&nbsp;dog</label>
```

Is there a way for JSF not to convert whitespaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSF doesn't do that. Your original message string **actually** contains non breaking spaces. JSF just HTML-encodes them to save your site from potential character encoding problems in the client side. Disabling the JSF HTML-encoding wouldn't fix the problem, the non breaking spaces would be still there; the only difference is that you risk malformed characters whenever the response encoding is not properly set.

If you want to get rid of non breaking spaces, then you need to fix it in the message source by replacing non breaking spaces (the `0xA0` characters) by normal spaces (the `0x20` characters).